# How do you scroll to an element that is within a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen scrollTo used for an entire page, but I'm looking to scroll content within just a div.

[image]

In the image, I have an element I want to scroll to. How to I bring the scroll to the top of the containing div (which already scrolls, I just want it to be automatic).

There is plenty of text below the highlighted element to facility scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `scrollTop` of the element which contains that element. And the value to set is actually the top position of that element which can be obtained using `$(element).position().top`.

So, the code you need is:

```
$j(scrollable_div).scrollTop($j(other_element).position().top)
```

NOTE: you made need to find the offset between other_element's containing element and the top of the page for it to scroll accurately.

Comment: If it's about the offset with respect to the *parent element*, I think one would rather want `.position`.

Comment: so.. I just tried this: $(".form.original_text").offset().top = 100 and the div didn't scroll =\

also tried $j(".form.original_text").scrollTop = $j(other_element).offset().top - 100  =\ nothing.

is there an example some where you could point me to?

Comment: @pimvdb - Thats correct `position` is to be used instead of `offset`.

Comment: @TheLindyHop - That is not the correct way to do, `scrollTop` is a method. Try this `$j(".form.original_text").scrollTop($j(other_element).position().top - 100)`

Comment: thank you!! that worked. I'll update your answer for you, then accepte.